# Update existing AKS for expiring custom SSL certificate using compute target

Tags: azure-aks, azure-machine-learning-service

I had set up my Azure Machine Learning workspace with an AKS compute target using the following code. The pem files are from our commercially purchased certificate. The AKS cluster has been working well for the past year. Now the certificate is expiring and needs to replaced.

```
ORIGINAL CODE USED FOR ATTACHING ML WORKSPACE TO AKS CLUSTER
============================================================
attach_config = 
AksCompute.attach_configuration(resource_id = resource_id,
                                cluster_purpose = AksCompute.ClusterPurpose.FAST_PROD,
                                load_balancer_type = 'InternalLoadBalancer', 
                                load_balancer_subnet = 'aks01-cluster-subnet')

attach_config.enable_ssl(ssl_cert_pem_file="mlsite_mycompany_com.pem",
                         ssl_key_pem_file="private.pem", 
                         ssl_cname="mlsite.mycompany.com")                                                

aks_target = ComputeTarget.attach(ws, cluster_name, attach_config)

aks_target.wait_for_completion(show_output = True)
```

I now have to update my certificate since it is nearing expiration. How do I do this? I am hoping I dont have to detach and run the command again with the new certificate pem files. How can I update the existing AKS compute (that runs Azure ML workload) for the new certificate using new pem files?

Thanks in advance,
Jake.

Comment: I think I finally found my answer here -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/v1/how-to-secure-web-service?view=azureml-api-1#update-the-tlsssl-certificate

Will report back after I use it and any lessons discovered

Comment: Turned out to work smoothly. The python SDK ran in 1 second. Then Updated the certificate on the App GW. Did checks and was getting the new cert and the endpoints were functioning.

Comment: Few things I had to remind myself from the first time. Cert and Key files have to be PEM encoded. Cert file needs full chain. Key file pem cannot be passphrase protected.